cline over multicolum and \cellcolor
I want to fix this cline over muticolumn-\cellcolor envirnoment. I have read some previous similar questions but I cant still fix it. I have used \nicetabular, hhline, threeparttable... but nothing works for me. Can you help me?
My table is the following:
\begin{table*}[t]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption example.}
    \label{tab:example}
    \begin{tabular}{c|cc|cccc}
        \cline{2-7}     
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}{\textbf{S0-DTP}}}                                  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}{\textbf{A30-DTP}}}                                                       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}{\textbf{S60-DTP}}}                                                       \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}\textbf{Options}}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}\textbf{$\zeta$~[rad]}} &\cellcolor[gray]{0.9} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \textbf{Max. I\textsubscript{a1,rms}} \\ \textbf{reduction} [\%]\end{tabular} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9} \textbf{$\zeta$~[rad]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \textbf{Max. I\textsubscript{a1,rms}} \\ \textbf{reduction} [\%]\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}\textbf{$\zeta$~[rad]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \textbf{Max. I\textsubscript{a1,rms}} \\ \textbf{reduction} [\%]\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Option 0}                                                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad}                        & 66.2\%                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{62.7\%}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{62.5\%}                                                              \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Option 1}                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad}                        & 79\%                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{85\%}                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{78.8\%}                                                              \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Option 2}                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\pi$~rad}                          & 80\%                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{28.3\%}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0~rad}                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0\%}                                                                 \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Option 5}                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\pi$~rad and $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad*}               & 78.3\%                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{35.1\%}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0~rad and $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad *}                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{22\%}                                                                \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Option 3\\ Option 4\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\pi$~rad and $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad*}               & 79\%                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\pi$~rad and $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad*}               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{85\%}                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0~rad and $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad *}                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{78.9\%}                                                              \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

I have other examples where it works but they have not multicolum envirmonment:
\begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \caption{Most relevant i\textsubscript{inv} harmonics which are cancelled depending on the DTP winding configuration.\textcolor{red}{No se centrar}}
    \label{tab:Cancelled harmonics DTP}
    \begin{center}
%   \begin{threeparttable}\centering
        \begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c|c|}
            \cline{2-4}%\hhline{{~----}}
            &\cellcolor[gray]{0.9} \textbf{S0-DTP} &\cellcolor[gray]{0.9} \textbf{A30-DTP} &\cellcolor[gray]{0.9} \textbf{S60-DTP} \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$C_{mn}^{iinv}$}} & - & ($m,\pm6$) & ($m,\pm3$) \\ \cline{2-4}
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}& - & ($m,\pm18$) & ($m,\pm9$) \\ \hline
        \end{NiceTabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \footnotesize
            \item $m$ = any carrier index e.g. $1,2,3,\cdots$.
        \end{tablenotes}
%   \end{threeparttable}
    \end{center}
\end{table}


the first example you show (\cline with colortbl) is explictly not supported see texdoc colortbl . NiceTabular should be able to do coloured pannels adjacent to rules though.

Here is a solution with {NiceTabular} of nicematrix. However, I recommend a table with the design of booktabs.
\documentclass[landscape]{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
\caption{Caption example.}
\label{tab:example}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccc}[color-inside,hvlines,corners]
\RowStyle[nb-rows=2,bold,rowcolor=[gray]{0.9}]{}
& \Block{1-2}{S0-DTP} 
  && \Block{1-2}{A30-DTP} 
    && \Block{1-2}{S60-DTP} \\ 
Options & $\zeta$~[rad] 
  & \Block{}{Max. I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction [\%]}
    & $\zeta$~[rad] 
      & \Block{}{Max. I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction [\%]}
         & $\zeta$~[rad] 
            & \Block{}{Max. I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction [\%]} \\ 
Option 0 
  & $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad 
    & 66.2\% 
      & $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad 
        & 62.7\% 
          & $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad 
            & 62.5\% \\ 
Option 1 
  & $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad 
    & 79\% 
      & $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad 
        & 85\% 
          & $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad 
            & 78.8\% \\ 
Option 2 
  & $\pi$~rad 
    & 80\% 
      & $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad 
        & 28.3\% 
          & 0~rad 
            & 0\% \\ 
Option 5 
  & $\pi$~rad and $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad* 
    & 78.3\% 
      & $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad 
        & 35.1\% 
          & 0~rad and $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad* 
            & 22\% \\ 
\Block{}{Option 3 \\ Option 4}
  & $\pi$~rad and $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad* 
    & 79\% 
      & $\pi$~rad and $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad* 
        & 85\% 
          & 0~rad and $\nicefrac{\pi}{2}$~rad* 
            & 78.9\% \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}



The base trick is to use \hhline (from the hhline package): in your case you want
\hhline{~|------}

so the rule is omitted in the first column and the corner is filled.
However, I take also the occasion to propose some improvements to your table.

Units (such as rad and %) declared in the column header should not be repeated in the data

Boldface is not needed as the gray background will provide the emphasis

You can remove almost all \multicolumn commands that clutter the code

\nicefrac is really awful


I also define a couple of local commands in order to further reduce the clutter in the code.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{hhline}


\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
\centering

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \args #1
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { $##1$ }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { ~and~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\caption{Caption example.}
\label{tab:example}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hhline{~|------}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}S0-DTP}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}A30-DTP}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}S60-DTP}
\\ \hline
\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Options
  & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}$\zeta$ (rad)
  & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}\splitcell{Max.\@ I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction (\%)}
  & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}$\zeta$ (rad)
  & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}\splitcell{Max.\@ I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction (\%)}
  & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}$\zeta$ (rad)
  & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}\splitcell{Max.\@ I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction (\%)}
\\ \hline
Option 0 & \args{\pi/2}        & 66.2 & \args{\pi/2}        & 62.7 & \args{\pi/2}      & 62.5
\\ \hline
Option 1 & \args{\pi/2}        & 79   & \args{\pi/2}        & 85   & \args{\pi/2}      & 78.8
\\ \hline
Option 2 & \args{\pi}          & 80   & \args{\pi/2}        & 28.3 & \args{0}          & 0
\\ \hline
Option 5 & \args{\pi,\pi/2}\,* & 78.3 & \args{\pi/2}        & 35.1 & \args{0,\pi/2}\,* & 22
\\ \hline
\splitcell{Option 3 \\ Option 4}
         & \args{\pi,\pi/2}\,* & 79   & \args{\pi,\pi/2}\,* & 85   & \args{0,\pi/2}\,* & 78.9
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table*}

\end{document}

Note. landscape is used just in order to get the table fit the margins. You probably need a wider text box.


Here I also propose a different version.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hhline}


\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
\centering

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \args #1
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { $##1$ }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { ~and~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\caption{Caption example.}
\label{tab:example-nice}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{6}{c}@{}}
\toprule
Options
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{S0-DTP}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{A30-DTP}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{S60-DTP}
\\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7}
  & $\zeta$ (rad)
  & \splitcell{Max.\@ I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction (\%)}
  & $\zeta$ (rad)
  & \splitcell{Max.\@ I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction (\%)}
  & $\zeta$ (rad)
  & \splitcell{Max.\@ I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction (\%)}
\\
\midrule
Option 0 & \args{\pi/2}        & 66.2 & \args{\pi/2}        & 62.7 & \args{\pi/2}      & 62.5
\\ \addlinespace
Option 1 & \args{\pi/2}        & 79   & \args{\pi/2}        & 85   & \args{\pi/2}      & 78.8
\\ \addlinespace
Option 2 & \args{\pi}          & 80   & \args{\pi/2}        & 28.3 & \args{0}          & 0
\\ \addlinespace
Option 5 & \args{\pi,\pi/2}\,* & 78.3 & \args{\pi/2}        & 35.1 & \args{0,\pi/2}\,* & 22
\\ \addlinespace
\splitcell{Option 3 \\ Option 4}
         & \args{\pi,\pi/2}\,* & 79   & \args{\pi,\pi/2}\,* & 85   & \args{0,\pi/2}\,* & 78.9
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table*}

\begin{table*}[t]
\centering

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \args #1
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { $##1$ }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { ~and~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\caption{Caption example.}
\label{tab:example}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hhline{~|------}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}S0-DTP}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}A30-DTP}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}S60-DTP}
\\ \hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}Options
  & $\zeta$ (rad)
  & \splitcell{Max.\@ I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction (\%)}
  & $\zeta$ (rad)
  & \splitcell{Max.\@ I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction (\%)}
  & $\zeta$ (rad)
  & \splitcell{Max.\@ I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction (\%)}
\\ \hline
Option 0 & \args{\pi/2}        & 66.2 & \args{\pi/2}        & 62.7 & \args{\pi/2}      & 62.5
\\ \hline
Option 1 & \args{\pi/2}        & 79   & \args{\pi/2}        & 85   & \args{\pi/2}      & 78.8
\\ \hline
Option 2 & \args{\pi}          & 80   & \args{\pi/2}        & 28.3 & \args{0}          & 0
\\ \hline
Option 5 & \args{\pi,\pi/2}\,* & 78.3 & \args{\pi/2}        & 35.1 & \args{0,\pi/2}\,* & 22
\\ \hline
\splitcell{Option 3 \\ Option 4}
         & \args{\pi,\pi/2}\,* & 79   & \args{\pi,\pi/2}\,* & 85   & \args{0,\pi/2}\,* & 78.9
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table*}

\end{document}



With use of the tabularray package you can get desired result too. Also the vertical spacing is a bit better:
\documentclass[landscape]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[t]
\centering
\caption{Caption example.}
\label{tab:example}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1}={2-Z}{},  hline{2-Z}={1-Z}{}, 
             vline{1}={2-Z}{},  vline{2-Z}={1-Z}{}, 
             colspec = {*{7}{Q[c,m]}},
             cell{1}{even} = {c=2}{font=\bfseries, bg=gray!15},
             row{2}  =  {font=\bfseries, bg=gray!15}
             }
        &   S0-DTP  
            &   &   A30-DTP 
                    &   &   A60-DTP
                            &               \\ 
Options &   $\zeta$~[rad] 
            &   {Max. I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction [\%]}
                &   $\zeta$~[rad] 
                    &   {Max. I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction [\%]}
                        &   $\zeta$~[rad] 
                            &   {Max. I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction [\%]}    
                                            \\ 
Option 0 
    &   $\pi/2$~rad 
        &   \qty{66.2}{\%}
            &   $\pi/2$~rad 
                &   \qty{62.7}{\%}
                    &   $\pi/2$~rad 
                        &   \qty{62.5}{\%}  \\
Option 1 
    &   $\pi/2$~rad 
        &   \qty{79}{\%}
            &   $\pi/2$~rad 
                &   \qty{85}{\%}
                    &   $\pi/2$~rad 
                        &   \qty{78.5}{\%}  \\
Option 2 
    &   $\pi$~rad 
        &   \qty{80}{\%}
            &   $\pi/2$~rad 
                &   \qty{28.3}{\%}
                    &   0~rad 
                        &   \qty{0}{\%}     \\
Option 5 
    &   $\pi$~rad and $\pi/2$~rad* 
        & \qty{78}{\%}
          & $\pi/2$~rad 
            & \qty{35.1}{\%} 
              & 0~rad and $\pi/(2$~rad* 
                & \qty{22}{\%}              \\ 
{Option 3 \\ Option 4}
    &   $\pi$~rad and $\pi/2$~rad* 
        &   \qty{79}{\%}
            &   $\pi$~rad and $pi/2$~rad* 
                &   \qty{85}{\%}
                    &   0~rad and $\pi/2$~rad* 
                        &   \qty{78.9}{\%}  \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}

As you can see, in MWE is also used siunitx package for nice writing of quantities.

Edit:
Off-topic: another possibilities to write decimal numbers in columns 3,5 and 7: columns are of S type:
\documentclass[landscape]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[t]
\centering
\caption{Caption example.}
\label{tab:example}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1}={2-Z}{},  hline{2-Z}={1-Z}{}, 
             vline{1}={2-Z}{},  vline{2-Z}={1-Z}{}, 
             colspec = {Q[c,m] *{3}{Q[c] 
                               Q[c, si={minimum-decimal-digits=1,
                                          table-format=2.1{\,\%}}]}},
             cell{3-Z}{3,5,7} = {appto={\,\%}},
             cell{1}{even} = {c=2}{guard, font=\bfseries, bg=gray!15},
             row{2}  =  {m, guard, font=\bfseries, bg=gray!15}
             }
        &   S0-DTP  
            &   &   A30-DTP 
                    &   &   A60-DTP
                            &               \\ 
Options &   $\zeta$~[rad] 
            &   {Max. I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction [\%]}
                &   $\zeta$~[rad] 
                    &   {Max. I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction [\%]}
                        &   $\zeta$~[rad] 
                            &   {Max. I\textsubscript{a1,rms} \\ reduction [\%]}    
                                            \\ 
Option 0 
    &   $\pi/2$~rad 
        &   66.2    
            &   $\pi/2$~rad 
                &   62.7    
                    &   $\pi/2$~rad 
                        &   62.5            \\
Option 1 
    &   $\pi/2$~rad 
        &   79
            &   $\pi/2$~rad 
                &   85
                    &   $\pi/2$~rad 
                        &   78.5  \\
Option 2 
    &   $\pi$~rad 
        &   80
            &   $\pi/2$~rad 
                &   28.3
                    &   0~rad 
                        &   0     \\
Option 5 
    &   $\pi$~rad and $\pi/2$~rad* 
        & 78
          & $\pi/2$~rad 
            & 35.1 
              & 0~rad and $\pi/(2$~rad* 
                & 22              \\ 
{Option 3 \\ Option 4}
    &   $\pi$~rad and $\pi/2$~rad* 
        &   79
            &   $\pi$~rad and $pi/2$~rad* 
                &   85
                    &   0~rad and $\pi/2$~rad* 
                        &   78.9  \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


